# postgres stored procedure or java code

Tags: postgresql, optimization, stored-procedures

I have a situation where there is large amount of data involved - about a million rows. I need to perform some looping through results and have many nested loops. With Java, it is taking about 15 minutes to perform all the operations. Would it be noticeable faster if I used stored procedures? I am familiar with Java, but not stored procedures.

Comment: Please explain what kind of operations you're trying to do. It'd be useful to have code examples that you're currently using. Have you tried to figure out what, in particular, is slowing down your query? Is it the looping a million times or the actual SQL queries nested within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pl/* functions will usually be faster because it removes the overhead of going back and forth with the database server.

As an aside, note that you can use java to write the stored procedures in question:

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pljava/

Lastly, try to rewrite part/all of what you're as a few big queries. It's usually faster to run a big query once than it is to loop through multitudes of small queries.